# Debug info from request handler

Tags: debug, endpoints, logging

I'm adding custom request handler using `add_action` and `register_rest_root`. Sometimes it's hanging and I'm stuck without any output. I would like to use something like

```
echo "Label";
```

to debug my code. But echo only outputs to the webpage source, which is not generated for failed request. How can I achieve this? If possible please advice solution which is applicable on the website already exposed to users.

Comment: If you set the constant [WP_DEBUG_LOG](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) on TRUE and the constant [WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) on FALSE, Wordpress will write the DEBUG log to an file and not to the screen. Or you can write easly your "echo"-DEBUG to an file (i know is old school :D ). By the way what is "register_request_root"?

Comment: Function name fixed.